# Adding existing Tomcat deployment to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat7

So we have Tomcat 7 running on it's own server. I can access it through a UNC path. Am I able to import the already-deployed Tomcat in my Netbeans? What I'm trying to achieve is; I need to be able to run servlet code and debug it/write tests for. Also would be hand if I could make changes and have it save/compile through Netbeans.

I'm currently using Atom and debugging with pen & paper. It's not ideal.

The folder structure goes like this:

```
[webapps]/[ROOT]/Applications/ApplicationName/html,css,jsp(views)
                /Reports/ReportName/html,css,jsp
                /WEB-INF/Applications/ApplicationName/java(servlets)
                        /Reports/ReportName/java
```

EDIT: Is it possible to create a WAR file from this webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have installed tomcat stand alone, and now you want to use it through Netbeans. Then if it is the case, it is simple, go to the left panel of your Netbeans (Projects, files, services) and choose "services -> servers". make a right clic on servers and choose "add a new server" the just follow.

Comment: Spot on thanks. I don't know why I couldn't find this on Google earlier, it's well documented..